# LibGDX fullscreen sizes

Tags: size, libgdx, fullscreen

I have tested a few values (by setting LwjglApplicationConfiguration width and height) to these values:

```
1920 | 1080
1024 | 768
 800 | 600
```

But I'm not able to get below those values while setting the fullscreen mode on.

So, what are the supported fullscreen sizes for libGDX?

EDIT 1: this is the source code trying to create new application with resolution of 600|480

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "Asteroid";
        cfg.width = 600;
        cfg.height = 480;
        cfg.resizable = false;
        cfg.fullscreen = true;

        new LwjglApplication(new Game(), cfg);
    }
}
```

Which throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't set display mode 600x480, fullscreen: true
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:131)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:131)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

On the other hand, similar code like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "Asteroid";
        cfg.width = 800;
        cfg.height = 600;
        cfg.resizable = false;
        cfg.fullscreen = true;

        new LwjglApplication(new Game(), cfg);
    }
}
```

Works without problem.

Comment: Huh? Fullscreen applications simply take up the whole screen. There is no notion of "supported sizes", because by default all sizes are supported.

Comment: Well, I mean the resolution and there is a difference between setting it to 1920|1080 and 800|600. But When I try setting it on (for example) 600|480, it crashes.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you're trying to do? What error does it crash with?

Comment: The question has been updated.

Comment: I think this will have more to do with your monitor than it does LWJGL or libGDX. What screen resolutions does your monitor support? You should probably just go fullscreen and then use a viewport to change the resolution of the game.

Comment: Well, I've tested it up on my 1366|768 netbook and got the same results.

Comment: Right. The problem is not that your monitor is too small. It's that it's too big. Can you tell your monitor to go as small as 600x480? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I though that rendering pixel style game with huge point in style of rendering it 'full HD' would cost more performace. Therefore I've tried this.

Comment: Like I said, to pull off that effect, you should simply use a viewport with whatever resolution you want. You shouldn't try to change the actual resolution of the monitor.

Comment: I am looking at the documentation and it basicaly says the same. So thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've added my suggestions as an answer, that way people with similar problems in the future will look there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to change the resolution of your monitor to something smaller than your monitor supports. Instead of changing the actual resolution of your monitor, you should simply use a viewport with whatever resolution you want.